# Accessing the filesystem of a modem

Tags: serial, modem

My goal is to access the file system of a modem/router i have.

On the circuitboard i found connectors (refdes J13 and J203) that the factory likely used to program or test the device.

J13 has solder on them and has marks of where 5 pins might have been connected, the thickness of two of the pins makes me think that its for  keeping the connector in place.

[image: J13/J203]

Could this be a serial port? if so is there theres a simple way to test it without a very high risk of breaking the modem?

Tools that i have in handy at the moment, multimeter, USB <-> UART connector, raspberry pi, beaglebone black, resistors, breadboards and other components that are in the general components category.

I also found a MX25L4006E chip which likely holds the firmware, i'm waiting for a bus pirate to be shipped so i might be able to dump the firmware.

I think that the ISP is capable of providing firmware updates and check status via the coax connector.

Any advice on how you would proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Could this be a serial port?" J302 yes, J13 looks much more like a unpopulated phone line port

Comment: "I think that the ISP is capable of providing firmware updates and check status via the coax connector." This is a cable modem, so it does DOCSIS, so yes, config and potentially firmware come from the ISP. Do a bit of research! For example, by watching https://events.ccc.de/congress/2015/Fahrplan/events/7133.html

Comment: @Marcus Müller: No, J13 is an unpopulated USB port. You can tell from the smaller pitch of the inner two pads.

Answer (score 4):

I used to manufacture a telecom device with a serial port.

While it looks similar to an RJ-14 phone jack it is not.  And RJ-14 connector has two rows of two pins with an offset.  See red circle.  The bigger holes are the connector's mounting holes.

Some times serial ports use RJ-14 but with 6 conductors.  If you look carefully at the gold contacts of the jacks in the plastic tube, there are gold contacts missing on sides of the four.

Because there are only 4 conductors and two mounting holes, it is not a serial port.

Because the for holes are in a single row, it is not a phone jack.

Looks very  much like a 4 pin, USB Type-A jack.

[image]

---

**RJ-14 Serial Port Pinout**
[image]

---

**4 Pin USB Jack**

[image]